# libuv and intel-iot-devkit/mraa for Beaglebone Black IO control

Tags: beagleboneblack, libuv

Does someone use libuv and the the intel-iot-devkit/mraa together doing some not so fast IO work. I do need any framework in C for doing some measurement and control stuff on a BBB. Or is there any better library or framework someone can recommend.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

GitHub . com/intel-iot-devkit/upm

Try this page on GitHub...

Seth

P.S. They have plenty of examples and software to try out for different modules.

Comment: many thanks, i know that but they use cpp, java and python there. And I am wondering if it is possible to use libuv so doing some async io in C with mraa

Comment: I got you now. I am sorry. If I come across any C language stuff for you, I will reply.

Comment: Many thanks I also will report here if I found out something new.

Answer (score 0):

the library I found from a person on github.com shows to be promising for C but not with upm as the basis for modules.

Try here with the C language in mind: https://github.com/shabaz123/iobb

I think it only works with the BBB and related boards.